# NextRouter was not mounted even though I am not using useRouter

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am getting this error:
"Error: NextRouter was not mounted. [https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-router-not-mounted"](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-router-not-mounted%22)

[image: Here is the image]

but the thing is, I am not using useRouter anywhere in my files. So I don't know why I have this error.